# Is this analytic continuation possible?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

I'n new to complex analysis and am a little flustered by the following function. I would like help understanding whether or not it is possible to analytically continue it outside of the unit circle.
$$f(z)=\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(1+z^k)$$
Using Maple, it seems to converge to $0$, at $z=(\exp(\frac{2\pi i}{2}),\exp(\frac{2\pi i}{4}),\exp(\frac{2\pi i}{6}),\dots)$ and diverge to infinity at $z=(\exp(\frac{2\pi i}{1}),\exp(\frac{2\pi i}{3}),\exp(\frac{2\pi i}{5}),\dots)$. This makes sense as when any of the first set of roots of unity are plugged into the function, you end up multiplying by 0 whereas with the other roots you just end up multiplying infinitely many numbers all greater than 1. Furthermore $f$ should converge to $0$ for any $even$ root of unity, $z=\exp(\frac{2\pi ik}{2n})$, and diverge for any *odd* root, $z=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi ik}{2n+1}\right)$.

This means that at any singularity, there are points infinitely close to it with $f(z)=0$, and for every point such that $f(z)=0$, there are infinitely many singularities near it. Is it possible (In theory or practice) to analytically continue $f$ outside the unit circle?

Edit: I am reading as we speak, a Wikipedia article that states that if a function has a set of singularities on its circle of convergence, and this set is $dense$, then every point on the circle must be a singularity. Except this function seems to contradict that as all of our $even$ roots are not singularities (unless secretly they are!).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by «singularity»?

Comment: That as we approach a particular point from inside the disk of convergence, |f(z)|->infinity.

Comment: Well, then it is not true that your even roots are not singularities.

Comment: Consider an «even root» $r$, a sequence of singularities $(z_n)_{n\geq1}$ which converges to $r$ (there is such a sequence because of density) and for each $n$ pick a point $u_n$ such that $|f(u_n)|>n$ and $|u_n-z_n|<\tfrac1n$; this also exists by your definitions. Then the sequence of the $u_n$ converges to $r$ and $|f(u_n)|$ goes to infinity. $r$ cannot be a non-singularity.

Comment: Oh I see! They are only non-singularities when approached from certain directions. (I.e. in a straight line from origin). Thank you.

Comment: If that answered your question, the best plan would be for you to write it down in an answer! :-)

Comment: I not quite sure how it works. I should answer my own question then?

Comment: Sure :-) ${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

No you cant. The function is a lacunary series with singularities at every point of its boundary of convergence so it cannot be continued. It is trapped in a valley surrounded by mountaintops. Pour soul...

Comment: This is not exacly what I had in mind when I suggested you add an answer. Unless you edit this into something sensible, I will  hae to delete it because it is not an answer :-/

Comment: I had to meet character count for it to post. I will change it however. I must ask you another question quickly while I have the chance. If I have a function $f$ that has a set of zeroes which is dense on the unit circle, can we say that every point on the unit circle is a zero? Logic suggests so. Maple (Antithesis of logic) suggests otherwise. The function I am talking about if f(z)=(1-z)(1-z^2)(1-z^3)..., and the set of zeroes are all the roots of unity.

Comment: Ask any new question as a question.

Comment: You should explain why each boundary point is a singularity.